# FAILED: out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/vndk_intermediates/check-list-timestamp

Tags: android-source

I compile android10 on Mac m2, lunch aosp_arm64-eng

I found the both have the same content in build/make/target/product/gsi/29.txt  and out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/vndk_intermediates/libs.txt

```
error: VNDK library list has been changed. Changing the VNDK library list is not allowed in API locked branches

***** diff: unrecognized option ****
The default diff(Apple diff (based on FreeBSD diff)) in Mac m2 that  can not be deleted. But other Mac is GNU diff3
```

[image]

```
[  7% 7816/108971] build out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/vndk_intermediates/check-list-timestamp
FAILED: out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/vndk_intermediates/check-list-timestamp
/bin/bash -c "(( diff --old-line-format=\"Removed %L\"    --new-line-format=\"Added %L\"      --unchanged-line-format=\"\"    build/make/target/product/gsi/29.txt out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/vndk_intermediates/libs.txt     || ( echo -e \" error: VNDK library list has been changed.\\n\" \"       Changing the VNDK library list is not allowed in API locked branches.\"; exit 1 )) ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/vndk_intermediates/ ) && (touch out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/vndk_intermediates/check-list-timestamp )"
diff: unrecognized option `--old-line-format=Removed %L'
usage: diff [-aBbdilpTtw] [-c | -e | -f | -n | -q | -u] [--ignore-case]
            [--no-ignore-case] [--normal] [--strip-trailing-cr] [--tabsize]
            [-I pattern] [-F pattern] [-L label] file1 file2
       diff [-aBbdilpTtw] [-I pattern] [-L label] [--ignore-case]
            [--no-ignore-case] [--normal] [--strip-trailing-cr] [--tabsize]
            [-F pattern] -C number file1 file2
       diff [-aBbdiltw] [-I pattern] [--ignore-case] [--no-ignore-case]
            [--normal] [--strip-trailing-cr] [--tabsize] -D string file1 file2
       diff [-aBbdilpTtw] [-I pattern] [-L label] [--ignore-case]
            [--no-ignore-case] [--normal] [--tabsize] [--strip-trailing-cr]
            [-F pattern] -U number file1 file2
       diff [-aBbdilNPprsTtw] [-c | -e | -f | -n | -q | -u] [--ignore-case]
            [--no-ignore-case] [--normal] [--tabsize] [-I pattern] [-L label]
            [-F pattern] [-S name] [-X file] [-x pattern] dir1 dir2
       diff [-aBbditwW] [--expand-tabs] [--ignore-all-blanks]
            [--ignore-blank-lines] [--ignore-case] [--minimal]
            [--no-ignore-file-name-case] [--strip-trailing-cr]
            [--suppress-common-lines] [--tabsize] [--text] [--width]
            -y | --side-by-side file1 file2
       diff [--help] [--version]
 error: VNDK library list has been changed.
        Changing the VNDK library list is not allowed in API locked branches.
12:06:16 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (04:31 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem for M2Pro MacBook pro for Android 11. The problem is indeed with Apple BSD version of diff. I installed the GNU version of diff (diff3), and the problem was solved. The best way is to install diffutils from homebrew. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/diffutils

`brew install diffutils`

[image]